# How would I redirect to a newly created post in WordPress on form submission?

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I am building a plugin that allows users to make a post and then I want it to redirect to the newly created post when the user submits the form. The problem I am running in to is getting the permalink for the new blog post and passing it through to the init function.

```
function create_post(){
    
if(is_user_logged_in())
{
    if(isset($_POST['ispost']))
    {
     
        global $current_user;
        get_currentuserinfo();

        $user_login = $current_user->user_login;
        $user_email = $current_user->user_email;
        $user_firstname = $current_user->user_firstname;
        $user_lastname = $current_user->user_lastname;
        $user_id = $current_user->ID;

        $post_title = $_POST['title'];
        $sample_image = $_FILES['sample_image']['name'];
        $post_content = $_POST['sample_content'];
        $category = $_POST['category'];

        $new_post = array(
            'post_title' => $post_title,
            'post_content' =>$post_content,
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'post_type' => $post_type,
            'post_category' => $category
        );
       // echo do_shortcode('[wpstream_go_live id="12"]');
        $pid = wp_insert_post($new_post);
        add_post_meta($pid, 'meta_key', true);
        
        if (!function_exists('wp_generate_attachment_metadata'))
        {
            require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/image.php');
            require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/file.php');
            require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/media.php');
        }
        if ($_FILES)
        {
            foreach ($_FILES as $file => $array)
            {
                if ($_FILES[$file]['error'] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK)
                {
                    return "upload error : " . $_FILES[$file]['error'];
                }
                $attach_id = media_handle_upload( $file, $pid );
            }
        }
        if ($attach_id > 0)
        {
            //and if you want to set that image as Post then use:
            update_post_meta($pid, '_thumbnail_id', $attach_id);
        }

        $my_post1 = get_post($attach_id);
        $my_post2 = get_post($pid);
        $my_post = array_merge($my_post1, $my_post2);
        
    }
    

}
else
{
    echo "<h2 style='text-align:center;'>User must be login for add post!</h2>";
}
}

add_action('init', 'myInit');
function myInit() {
    if (isset($_POST['ispost'])) {
        $errors = myFormValidation();
        if (empty($errors)) {
            //Do whatever you want here 
            header('Location: ' . get_permalink());
           
        }
        //Set the errors here
    }
}
```

The only thing that I can think of is using sessions to pass the permalink from one function to another. What would be the best way of getting and passing the permalink to the init function? Also when I exit after the header() it returns a blank page but if I don't it works.

Comment: You should be able to call `wp_safe_redirect` directly after you insert and update meta data, you shouldn't need to wait until the init hook later

Comment: It says that I am trying to modify header info after header has already been sent when I do this.

Comment: In what hook are you invoking `create_post`?

Comment: create_post is being invoked when a user submits a form. No hook used

Comment: Okay, well the `init` hook runs after all plugin code has run so you'll run into the same issue there, too. At the end of your insert/update I would troubleshoot using [`headers_sent($filename, $line)`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.headers-sent.php) and inspect those two variables to see who sent that. It might be core, unfortunately. You can also instead put a `die` at the end of your update and use your browser to manually inspect things. In the past this was often caused by whitespace or a BOM at the top of files before the opening `<?php` directive.

Comment: After `$my_post = array_merge($my_post1, $my_post2);` add `wp_safe_redirect( get_post_permalink($pid) ); die;`

Answer (score 1):

You can redirect the user after processing the form by using JavaScript. Something like...

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
echo 'window.location = "' . $url . '"';
echo '</script>';
```